# iOS - moving/cropping UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, crop

I have a UIView in a table view section header that I would like to crop to make shorter or longer programmatically. I determine the height of the section header by counting the number of elements that will be displayed in the header. For example, if I support 5 max items, my view will look like this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3 
Item 4
Item 5
```

But in cases where I only want to display 3 items I would like to crop the top off:

```
Item 3
Item 4 
Item 5
```

I'm cropping from the top because I have design on the bottom of the view that I don't want to lose.

I tried just moving the UIView's frame up by the factor I needed, but the section header does not cover up anything that goes beyond it's upper limit. Is there anyway to chop off the top two items and move the rest of the view up?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create some `UIView` that will contain the `UIView` of your header. Set property `clipsToBounds` of this container to `YES`.

Comment: This works. For others, a little more detail in your explanation. Set the UIView of your table cell to clip to bounds. Then dragging the view within the table cell view offscreen will actually move the view off screen. Thanks!